# Return name instead of ID to table

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, .net-core

[image: Table image]

My code returns userid, categoryid, locationid instead of the names to my list view.

I want to return names instead of id
//This is the get method in the service

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<JobViewModel>> GetAllJobsAsync()
        {
            var jobs = _appDbContext.Jobs
                .Include(j => j.Category)
                .Include(j => j.Location)
                .Include(j => j.User)
                .ToList();
            return jobs.Select(job => new JobViewModel(job));
         
        }
```

//Get method in the controller

```
  public async Task<IActionResult> ListOfJobs()
        {
            var list = await _jobService.GetAllJobsAsync();
            return Ok(list);
        }

//This is the JobViewModel 
public JobViewModel(JobClass job)
        {
            JobId = job.JobId;
            JobTitle = job.JobTitle;
            Description = job.Description;
            Requirement = job.Requirement;
            Experience = job.Experience;
            Salary = job.Salary;
            DatePosted = job.DatePosted;
            Deadline = job.Deadline;
            UserId = job.Id;
            CategoryId = job.CategoryId;
            LocationId = job.LocationId;


        }
        public Guid JobId { get; set; }
        public string JobTitle { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public string Requirement { get; set; }
        public string Experience { get; set; }
        public int Salary { get; set; }
        public DateTime DatePosted { get; set; }
        public DateTime Deadline { get; set; }
        public Guid UserId { get; set; }
        public int LocationId { get; set; }
        public int CategoryId { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<CategoryViewModel> Categories { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<LocationViewModel> Locations { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: So, ... show us your code then. Impossible to say what to change otherwise.

Comment: @TheGamer: Code related question without code in it is unlikely to get useful answer.

Comment: This site is for specific issues, not general programming tips. We can tell you generally how to retrieve related data but that's not a specific issue. If you expect us to tell you how to change what you have done, we need to know what you have done. I suspect that this is actually going to be a SQL question and have nothing at all to do with ASP.NET.

Comment: Can you show us your JobViewModel?

Comment: I suspect that you will need to access another table in which the value in "PostedBy" is used as an index.